# Why I can't free an array inside a struct?

Tags: c

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    TypeCon *Pags;
    // Some stuff
}TypeMem;
```

And I have a function which mallocs this pointer called Pags.

```
void StartsTypeMem(TypeMem *Mem, int memorySize){
    Mem->Pags = (TypeCon*) malloc(memorySize);
   // Some stuff
}
```

Then I use this TypeMem in my code, but I just can't use free() on Pags when I'm done. As I understood, you can't free arrays malloc'd in another function... but I don't know... what i'm doing wrong?

in main():

```
TypeMem Memo; 
StartsTypeMem(&Memo, size); 

// Some stuff using the TypeMem 

KillTypeMen(&Memo);
```

KillTypeMen could be:

```
void KillTypeMem(TypeMem *Mem){
    free(Mem->Pags);
    // Some stuff
}
```

---

Error message (taken from comment to one answer):

*** glibc detected**  ./smv: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x098db448 ** smv: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed. Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)

Comment: _How_ do you try to free it? What's happening when you do? Are you sure you don't write beyond the end of the allocated memory?

Comment: "but I just can't use `free()`" - why? - "you can't free arrays malloc'd in another function" - why couldn't you?

Comment: Show the code that calls `free()`. If you get a compiler error or warning, show those too. We don't know what "I just can't use `free()`" means, you have to tell us.

Comment: I would say that the error message is typical of when you write beyond the allocated memory. You have to go though your code and make sure you stay within the limits of the allocated memory.

Comment: Well, that's a hell of assertion.

Comment: Since you seem to be using Linux, you can use tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find these kind of errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
void KillTypeMem(TypeMem *Mem){
    free(Mem->Pags);
   // Some stuff
}
```

But you need to make sure you are tracking the lifetime of the struct correctly and never use something after you freed it. And you also need to make sure it is freed only after it has been allocated, or initialized to `NULL` (I think it is legal to call `free` on `NULL`, correct me if i'm wrong).

Also, if you allocated `TypeMem` dynamically, you obviously need to free `Mem->Pags` before you free `Mem`.

**Edit**

The problem does not come from the `StartsTypeMem` and `KillTypeMem` functions, those are absolutely fine. The following example compiles and runs without error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct { int i; } TypeCon;

typedef struct {
    TypeCon *Pags;
}TypeMem;

void StartsTypeMem(TypeMem *Mem, int memorySize){
    printf("Allocate\n");
    Mem->Pags = (TypeCon*) malloc(memorySize);
}

void KillTypeMem(TypeMem *Mem){
    printf("free\n");
    free(Mem->Pags);
}

int main(){
    TypeMem Memo;
    StartsTypeMem(&Memo, 10*sizeof(TypeCon));
    KillTypeMem(&Memo);
    printf("done\n");
}
```

You need to isolate the error. We cannot help you without the code, but the error does not come from an allocation or a free problem for `TypeMem.Pags`.

Go though all the "Some stuff" carefully.

One quick thought: you do use `sizeof(TypeCon)` at some point in your code, right? You are not calling `malloc` directly with an array size, like `Mem->Pags = (TypeCon*) malloc(10)`, because if you do that, it is definitely the source of your problem.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to free Mem, just Mem->Pags. I'm trying to do this, with the same code you sent but it results in a error.

    TypeMem Memo;
    StartsTypeMem(&Memo, size);

    // Some stuff using the TypeMem
    KillTypeMen(&Memo);

Comment: *** glibc detected *** ./smv: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x098db448 ***
smv: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)

Comment: Edit your original post, add a minimal example showing how you allocate and free everything.